# FCM Data Message not deliver to devices

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging, php-curl

I am using php to send fcm data message from to topics anytime i send message i get the response below.

```
{"message_id":8846044152001290063}
```

i don't really know if this mean failure or success also below is my php function used to send **notice** from **server**.

```
function pushNotice($title, $topic, $message, $sender, $timeStamp, $destination, $date){

//$registrationIds = array( TOKENS );
// prep the bundle
$msg = array(
    'notice_body'  => $message,
    'notice_title'     => $title,
    'notice_sender'     => $sender,
    'notice_timestamp'     => $timeStamp,
    'notice_destination'     => $destination,
    'notice_date'     => $date,
    'vibrate'   => 1,
    'sound'     => 1
);

$fields = array(
    'to'  => '/topics/'.$topic,
    'data'          => $msg,
    'priority' => 'high'
);

$headers = array(    
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Authorization:key=AAAAC7uT-N8:APA91bHD-T5Whu97Gv5A4PtbBm7LgEAQFwH9HBro2gJJfR0sw2UCLs-CTwxNThg3KFL23XVwc7X4n3..............'
);

$url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
$result = curl_exec($ch );
if ($result === FALSE) {
    die('FCM Send Error: ' . curl_error($ch));
}
curl_close ( $ch );

echo $result;
    return $result;   
 }
```

Comment: if you getting this message {"message_id":8846044152001290063} than your php function works fine, Cross check android side implementation

Comment: What could be the reason why onmessagereceived isn't getting called